# Need help with brute force code for crypt(3)

Tags: c, brute-force, permutation, crypt

I am trying to develop a program in C that will "crack" the crypt(3) encryption used by UNIX.
The most naive way to do it is brute forcing I guess. I thought I should create an array containing all the symbols a password can have and then get all possible permutations of them and store them in a two-dimensional array (where all the 1 character passwords get's saved in the first row etc.) through for loops. Is there any better way to do this? It's pretty messy with the loops.

Comment: You don't want to store all the permutations - just test & discard as you create them

Comment: Do you **really** have enough memory to store all possible permutations?

Comment: No my bad. I meant to store every permutation I get temporary in a an array of chars that I will pass to crypt. That is : 1)Permute 2)Save on a string (array) 3)Pass. On next permutation the previous string will get replaced. I just figured I will use a two dimensional array because not all passwords have the same length (and I cannot have empty array slots).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming only 62 different characters can be used, storing all the possible 8 character passwords requires 62^8=198 Terabytes.

To anwser you *loop* question, here is some code to loop over all the possible passwords of a given len, using the characters for a given set:

```
int len = 3;
char letters[] = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
int nbletters = sizeof(letters)-1;

int main() {
    int i, entry[len];
    for(i=0 ; i<len ; i++) entry[i] = 0;
    do {
        for(i=0 ; i<len ; i++) putchar(letters[entry[i]]);
        putchar('\n');
        for(i=0 ; i<len && ++entry[i] == nbletters; i++) entry[i] = 0;
    } while(i<len);
}
```

The main part is the last *for* loop. In most cases, it only increments the first entry, and stops there, as this entry has not reached nbletters. If the entry reaches nbletter, it means it has to return to zero, and it's the turn of the next entry to be incremented. It is indeed an unusual loop condition: the loop continues until there is no overflow. The looping only occurs in the worst case: when several entries are on the last element.

Imagine the case where the current word is "zzzc". In turn, each entry is incremented, its overflow is detected, it is reset to 0, and the next entry is considered, until the last entry which does not overflow, to give "000d".

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer!
Could you please explain the part where you write :
    ++entry[i] == nbletters;
I can't figure out this condition so I am having problem understanding all that line, which is the most important I guess!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As the commenters on the question point out - you don't have the necessary RAM, and you don't need to store it all.

Covering the permutations in sort sequence is not the most efficient approach to password cracking, although it will ultimately be effective.

An approach to achieving full coverage is to iterate 0 through the number of permutations and encode the value with the size of your character set as a base. This can be scaled to the size of your character set quite easily.

(pseudocode, but you get the idea)

```
passChars = '[all characters used in this attempt]'

permutationCount = 8^len(passChars) #crypt(3) only uses 8 chars

output = ''

for looper = 0 to permutationCount - 1
    localTemp = looper
    while localTemp > 0
        output += passchars[localTemp%len(passchars)] # % being modulus
        localTemp = floor(localTemp/len(passChars))
```