# What would be an efficient way to add multithreading to this simple algorithm?

Tags: c, multithreading, algorithm, brute-force

I would say my knowledge in C is fair, and I wish to extend a program to enhance my knowledge of parallel programming.

It essentially the program I am refering to is a brute force generator, to increment through passwords such as from 0000 .. zzzz of a specific character set:
[Need help with brute force code for crypt(3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749657/need-help-with-brute-force-code-for-crypt3)

The algorithm is outlined below (credit to Jerome for this)

```
int len = 3;
char letters[] = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
int nbletters = sizeof(letters)-1;

int main() {
    int i, entry[len];
    for(i=0 ; i<len ; i++) entry[i] = 0;
    do {
        for(i=0 ; i<len ; i++) putchar(letters[entry[i]]);
        putchar('\n');
        for(i=0 ; i<len && ++entry[i] == nbletters; i++) entry[i] = 0;
    } while(i<len);
}
```

In what logical way would you say this could be extended by multithreading?

CUDA is a silly, if simple, solution. I had heard of OpenMP which in my books looks like a good solution, how do you think this could be split up to benefit from multiple cores of my computer? I.e. core 1 computing aaaa..ffff, and core 2 computing ffff...zzzz, is this the only method that would make sense with this?

Comment: What about the `entry` array be something more realistic like `{3, 21, 10}` not all zeros. And you can add the desired output as well.

Comment: @vbence, I've no clue what he did there, from other algorithms I saw that numerics represent letters in a charset (and then you can define arbitrary charsets), although I am unsure, I'll have to tinker with it, finding nothing else to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you answered your own question. The aaaa..ffff on thread #1 and ffff..zzzz on thread #2 is probably the way to go, except to maybe break it down into more threadable parts in case you have more cores available.  Trying to start a thread to perform some part of the do loop would probably introduce more overhead than benefit in such a tight algorithm.

Comment: I am grateful, do you have any recommendations to go about this? There is a pthreads-win32 implementation so likely just those will work.

Comment: Yes, I had pursued with pthreads and they seem so incredibly easy. The algorithm however seems to not like being inside a function, I'll maybe find an algorithm that is more stable to changes.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to see your output characters in the **order** they are referenced in the `entry` array.

This is a sequential operation you can not parallelize it.

**Edit:**

OK, now I see how wrong my was are :) You actually CAN parallelize this program, but you have to implement an additional layer handling the order of letters in the output. Also need to implement synchronization.

Comment: I don't think that is the OP's intention. The example program is a bit irritating, I think in the final program the `putchar()` will be replaced with passing the password to a decryption routine that reports success/failure and order won't matter.

Comment: Yes, the order of the string matters, the order of the operations does not however and is irrelevant to my program.

Comment: @Kenshin What do you mean "the order of the string matters"? Why do you care what order strings are generated in?

Comment: @Kenshin Can you clarify what you meant to say, then?

Comment: @Nick, I believe I misread the answer, there is no need to take anything of it. I believe I was thinking of that if the order was not important, then I could not separate ranges to feed to threads which is not entirely true.

Comment: @Kenshin I'm just asking for clarification. If the order you generate strings in (not the order of the letters in the string) matters, while you could still parallelize it, it wouldn't be very efficient: merging the results would be just as expensive as generating them in the first place.